# HTML opacity how can I set children...HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an opacity question, I want to have a div black bacground with opacity .1 and on another div transparent background opacity 1. Here is my code:

```
 <div style="width:95%; height:468px; background:black; float:left; opacity:0.1;">
 <div style="margin-left:1em; margin-top:1em; font-size:14px;">
 <table width=100%>
 <tr valign=top>
<td></td>
<td width=100%>
<h4>Change Password</h4>
<form method="post" action="settings.php">
<table cellpadding=10>
<tr>
    <td>Current Password</td>
    <td style="padding-left:2em;">user</td>
</tr>    
</table>
</form>
</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4yYGe/

How can I set it right my second div barely displays. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern browsers you could set the outer div's background to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. As opacity is inherited. So if the parent is set to .5, even if the child is set to 1, it will still display to .5 given the parent's setting. Another example: If the parent were set to .5 and the child to .5, the child would appear as .25 as would be set to half the opacity of the parent.

Cuberto's answer is the workaround you are likely looking for--don't give the div an opacity setting, but instead give the background color an opacity setting.

Barring that, you have to decouple the child div and instead use absolute or relative positioning instead. Alternatively, add another child div that is then a sibling and set the opacity on one of the siblings.